# Edit in place with jQuery

Tags: jquery

With reference to [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/czq2k4ar/), i'm implementing a very basic edit in place system.

This is the script:

```
// fire all the click on the spans having the class "edit"
$(document).on('click', '.edit', function() {
    // toggle the spans and show the one to edit the data
    $(this).closest('td').find('span').toggle();
    // listen for the first click outside of the span with class "editing" that is ":visible"
    $(document).one('click', ':not(.editing:visible)', function() {
        // toggle the span with class "editing" that is ":visible"
        $('.editing:visible').closest('td').find('span').toggle();
    });
});
```

It works fine if to close the `.editing` you click outside of the `table`, but if you click on another `td` while theres an `.editing` open, it will correctly close the previous `.editing` but it won't let you open the new one until you click outside of the `table`! What's wrong in the code?

Comment: Have you looked this plugin? http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable

Answer (score 1):

Doing this is rather complicated, but assuming you want to edit some text, you will need some input-based element. So you can simply bind [blur](http://api.jquery.com/blur/) event hander to this inputs and close them.

Full example is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/czq2k4ar/9/), jquery code:

```
$(document).on('click', '.edit', function(event) {
    $(this).closest('td').find('span').toggle().find('input').focus();
});

$(document).on('blur', 'input.editing', function(event) {
    $(this).closest('td').find('span').toggle();
});
```

Edit after comment:

```
$(document).on('click', 'body', function(event) {
    var target = $(event.target);
    $('.editing').not(target).hide().sibling('.edit').show();
});
```

This should help you. Basically on every click it will hide all .editing element that was not clicked on.

Second edit:

New [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xphmeupy/), and some code -

```
$(document).on('click', '.edit', function(event) {
    $(this).closest('td').find('span').toggle().find('select').focus();
});

$(document).on('blur', 'select._target', function(event) {
    $(this).closest('td').find('span').toggle();
});

$(document).on('change', 'select._target', function(event){
    $(this).trigger('blur');
});
```

Basically, I`m automatically focusing the select inside the span, and allowing blur do all the job. The change event is for selecting some value - assuming you want close the selection after picking. Tested in fiddle, hope it will help :)

For select and input version change first two event handlers like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.edit', function(event) {
    $(this).closest('td').find('span').toggle().find('select, input').focus();
});

$(document).on('blur', 'select._target, input._target', function(event) {
    $(this).closest('td').find('span').toggle();
});
```

Comment: nice solution, unfortunately in the real code i have basically dropdown menus in the `.editing` `span` :(

Comment: Improved answer, hope it will help :)

Comment: this way i have the same behavior of my initial question

Comment: Can you share full code with dropdown elements? I`m using my own and have nothing for testing.

Comment: it's a little bit complicated as it is a very long code generated by a PHP function, anyway i've edited the first td (left up corner) with a dropdown if it may be useful for you...here it is: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/czq2k4ar/10/)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72424/discussion-between-corwincz-and-mariano).

Comment: this works perfectly with dropdowns, but not with text inputs :D anyway thanks for your help, i'll try to mix up the second and the third tip you gave me!

Comment: Edited, added support for select and input inside of span.